# featured image in database but not in backend

Tags: wordpress

to my understanding, the information about the featured image of a post in WordPress is being stored in the database in *wp_postmeta* table with key *_thumbnail_id* ...

I have the weird situation that for some posts where there is a features image set in the database, this image also shows up in the WordPress backend in the featured image admin widget -- but for other posts there is a featured image set in the database, but it doesn't appear in the WordPress backend.

[see screenshots (sorry, in German) of the database entry plus WordPress backend for both situations - upper where the issue appears, lower where the image also shows up in the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYITZ.jpg)

What I want to achieve is having all featured images also showing up in the backend.

(we're talking about hundreds of posts, so it's not really an option to manually edit each of these postings).

Answer (score 0):

I found what causes the issue - in case someone else runs into this problem, too:

Years ago I was using the NextGen Gallery plugin which obviously was sustituting WordPress' core system for featured images (don't know whether the actual version of NGG still acts like this, though). Meaning: It stored the attachment_id of the features image at the right place, but did put only the smalles thumbnail version of an image into the regular folder for images in WordPress and kept the bigger versions of the image within the NGG system. Hence: There is a feautres image, but WordPress can's access it ...

Eventually I had to go throug more than 100 posts to fix this manually.